# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host : <host name> port : 25 response: 554

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mail using java mail api. My smtp server is an ibm server. I am facing this exception

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host : <host name> port : 25 response: 554
```

pls help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't exactly programming related - it's SMTP server configuration issue.

Comment: You should probably talk to the people who administer the SMTP server, and ask *them* why it would send you a `554` error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting an error code 554: `Access Denied Relay`.

It can be caused because your SMTP server doesn't recognise your petition as legit, and blocks it as if it were SPAM.

Perhaps your from account doesn't match the server expected domain, or you need add some aditional autentication parameters to your SMTP connection (hard to know without more information on your code).