# javax.mail exception running a Grails app on heroku

Tags: email, grails, heroku

I have a Grails app on Heroku and suddenly I started getting this exception, when ever an email was sent: javax.mail.MessagingException:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: smtpout.secureserver.net, port: 25, response: 554
```

I did a restart on my app and things came back to normal, Heroku was sending mails again, but as I did nothing to my code, I guess things can malfunction again at any moment.

I'm using javax.mail to send my emails, with the grails mail plugin, it works perfectly in other servers.

I read in the Heroku support that I needed to use an external SMTP service, but it also says that I can use javax.mail to build mail functionality on top of external SMTP services, so, can't I use javax.mail without an external SMTP service in Heroku? why is that? why do I get to send emails for a while without the external SMTP service? wich would be the best choice for an external SMTP service in the heroku addons?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ana a few things there:

[javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host : <host name> port : 25 response: 554](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429766/javax-mail-messagingexception-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-host-name-port)

1. Check out above link
2. If this is the actual msg returned: smtpout.secureserver.net, port: 25

Then I would suggest when it next happens you open a terminal to the box hosting your site and run

```
telnet smtpout.secureserver.net 25
```

or

```
nc -z -v smtpout.secureserver.net 25
```

Here is my local host check:

```
nc -z -v localhost 25
nc: connect to localhost port 25 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
 nc -z -v localhost 22
Connection to localhost 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

I would also check out

```
netstat -plant |grep ":25"
```

I think it may be that if it is an external smtp server it is flooded and can not accept any more connections, it could be your app has flooded it and caused it to have no more pool for connections and a restart has removed all waiting tasks

It maybe worth while writing a cron entry that checks how many outgoing smtp connections are open at any time and above a certain amount to alert you - this way you can see when it is coming

Just in case it ever happens again - there are some things you could research :

I probably would start looking at the testing plugins at the bottom and setting up a demo site to try to work out what is going on -

Also may be related to content being sent to the email why it had crashed - something incorrect etc... (so trying capture what happened at the time would probably be of real use)

grails-tcpmon http://grails.org/plugin/tcpmon

significant mail : http://grails.org/plugin/sendgrid  http://grails.org/plugin/postmark

Asynchronus mail: http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail

using log4j for sending emails: 
http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/burt_beckwith/2010/02/using_gmail_with_a_log4j_smtp_appender_in_grails

http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/08/13/send-mail-via-log4j-with-smtp-appender/

Testing:
http://grails.org/plugin/greenmail
http://grails.org/plugin/dumbster

Comment: Tks for your answer, I was looking for something in my app to close connections but I don't have it, also I'm not using any SMTP addon, in my heroku, I'm doing it directly from my app with javax.mail, do you think that may be the problem? it hasn't happened again yet

Comment: So far as grails goes, if you are using the mail plugin then there is no need to call closures as per instructions http://grails.org/plugin/mail   | I don't have a lot of knowledge on heroku but did find these which may be of help http://blog.flurdy.com/2012/05/send-email-via-sendgrid-on-heroku-using.html | http://nakkaya.com/2009/11/10/using-java-mail-api-from-clojure/

Comment: I haven't been able to test this, It hasn't happened again. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it - left lots of links for stuff to look into